# How to prevent the beep sound caused by alt key pressed in a WinForms TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a routine that allows the user to replicate keyboard shortcuts into a textbox for 'custom keyboard shortcuts' customization, but every time the alt key is pressed with another letter, it produces another sound.

I'm capturing the keys in the textbox_keydown event to parse the modifiers + other keys into a readable Shift + A or Ctrl + Shift + B manner into that very same textbox. Should I be doing this in a different event like textbox_previewkey instead of textbox_keydown? How can I prevent the alt modifier key + a letter or number causing the Beep sound?

the textbox is just a normal .net 3.5 textbox with the only edited properties of it being the ReadOnly property to false. Is there a better way I could re-do this?

I'm currently just checking that if any modifiers keys are pressed and then + a-z or 0-9, then to go ahead and input the appropriately pressed keys into that same textbox like Shift + A or Ctrl + Shift + Y.

Comment: +1 Your question & answer was usefull for me. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a message box in the method call, things might not work as expected. See [cannot-disable-beep-sound-on-textbox-keydown-event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219597/cannot-disable-beep-sound-on-textbox-keydown-event)

Answer (score 5):

Handle the KeyDown event of the TextBox, e.g. with void HandleKeyDown(object source, KeyEventArgs e) and inside enter: `if (e.Alt) e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`.

(also works for the Return key)

Answer (score 1):

Disregard, I was able to solve the problem by suppressing the keycode right from the start without affecting it's normal functions. Here is what I used:

```
e.SuppressKeyPress = (e.KeyCode == e.KeyCode);
```

Comment: You realize that this is the same as saying e.SuppressKeyPress = true, right?

Comment: unless `KeyCode` returns `double.Nan` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `e.Handled = true;` in order to prevent the keystroke from bubbling up.

Comment: HI 
I had the same problem, e.Handled = true didn't solve the problem. e.SuppressKeyPress = true did it.