# BEEP on form instance creation. Keydown suppressed already

Tags: c#, textbox, instance-variables, beep

I have a text box which creates a form when enter is pressed.
It is a single line textbox.

I have suppressed the keypress and using breakpoints I have determined that the "BEEP" that is being played comes when I create a form instance...

```
 private void txtcust_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string searchtext;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            searchtext = txtcust.Text;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

            frmcustlist frmcust = new frmcustlist(searchtext);
            frmcust.ShowDialog();

        }

    }
```

The beep gets played after this code plays:

```
frmcustlist frmcust = new frmcustlist(searchtext);
```

I have tried numerous things including handling the key up, playing with AcceptsReturn and also multiline.
Multiline works if TRUE, but then obviously the textbox now has 2 lines.
Surely this isn't the answer??

Thanks for any advice
Gangel

UPDATE:  Added e.handled - Still got a beep/

```
private void txtcust_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string searchtext;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            searchtext = txtcust.Text;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            e.Handled = true;


            frmcustlist frmcust = new frmcustlist(searchtext);
            frmcust.ShowDialog();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable beep of enter and escape key c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952932/disable-beep-of-enter-and-escape-key-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi @Sinatr I dont believe this is a duplicate.  My event beeping is not keypress or down or up as far as i can tell. It is the actual code for the instance creation.
Even frmcust.ShowDialog isnt causing the beep. Just the instance part..

Comment: I am sure it is. Beeping happens due to `KeyDown` event handler code, e.g. move it into button `Click` event handler and there will be no beeping anymore (unless created form produces it, but that's another story). And the answer in duplicate suggest to set `e.Handled = true`, just add this line = no more beeping.

Comment: Thanks @Sinatr for the responses, however i have added e.handled and i still get the beep. I did have it before, and removed it, because it didnt seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with .Text being dirty still..?? I really have no idea!