# C# How to remove 'ding' system sound when w,s,a,d buttons are pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

First of all i can not use

```
KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress
```

Because i am using Key_Down event to listen to input from the user,essentially i am making a Pacman game and when the user presses **W** or **S** or **A** or **D** there is a 'ding' sound that windows makes.I want to disable it but i do not know how.
My Key_Down method:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) //A press moves left
        {
            k = 1;
            left = true;
            right = false;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.D) //D press moves right
        {
            k = 3;
            left = false;
            right = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
        {
            k = 2;
            left = false;
            right = false;
            up = false;
            down = true;
        }
        else if(e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
        {
            k = 4;
            left = false;
            right = false;
            up = true;
            down = false;
        }
```

My form uses buttons that i disable when the user presses the 'Start' Button.
i use:

`Button.Disable = true;`
is it perhaps caused by the buttons still listening for user input or what?
I also have some labels and a Listbox,do i need to disable them too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable beep of enter and escape key c sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952932/disable-beep-of-enter-and-escape-key-c-sharp)

Comment: Set the event as handled?

Comment: I set it as handled but it still makes the sound

Comment: The linked code also uses `e.SuppressKeyPress = true`. You should try that.

Comment: Documentation for SupressKeyPress: 'You can assign true to this property in an event handler such as KeyDown in order to prevent user input. '
But i want user input...

Comment: You'll have to make up your mind.  You can use wasd to move a game object *or* you can use it for text input.  Not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using .NET framework then add this line of code just after your handling:

```
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```