# MessageBox plays different chimes depending on event

Tags: c#, winforms

I am displaying a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox` to alert the user that an error has occurred. Here is the method to do so:

```
private void TryToExit()
{
    if (ERROR OCCURRED)
    {
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show("Name already in use!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        // Focus the textbox so its text can be selected
        nameTextBox.Focus();
        nameTextBox.SelectAll();
    }
    else
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

There are two scenarios in which this method can be called:

1  The OK button on the form is pressed:

```
private void OkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TryToExit();
}
```

2  The user presses the return key while in the textbox

```
private void NameTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (nameTextBox.Focused)
    {
        // Try to close the dialog if the user hits the return key
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            TryToExit();
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `TryToExit()` in the first scenario (OK button), the message box plays the sound `Windows Foreground.wav`, but when I call `TryToExit()` from the second scenario (return key), the message box plays the sound `Windows Background.wav`. It's kind of annoying how the two different sounds play, and I would like to know if there is a way to make sure that the same sound effect is played in either situation.

Comment: See [Disable beep of enter and escape key c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13952932/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, `BeginInvoke()` did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `BeginInvoke()` for the message box.

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(() => DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(...));
```

See the comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13953616/6575658)