# Cannot disable beep sound on textbox keydown event

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is my code for disabling beep sound when I press "Enter" on textbox `KeyDown()` event:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    SaveData();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

But it keeps beeping when I press "Enter" on textbox. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't it a sound produced by the operating system ?

Comment: Yes Windows beep sound. How can I disable it?

Comment: @Dhaval as you see from my code I am also setting `Handled` and `SuppressKeyPress` to true, but it's not working.

Comment: @Shohin sorry it my mistake

Comment: Maybe sound is made by something else? Can't think of what, perhaps another `TextBox` or the form.

Comment: @Sinatr `SaveData()` private void pops messagebox if some textbox is not filled. Also after saving data it shows MessageBox with success message. Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: just comment it and see for yourself =)

Comment: Mute the speakers? :)

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952932/disable-beep-of-enter-and-escape-key-c-sharp

Comment: @N4TKD it's not a duplicate, are you blind? I am using the correct answer from that post, but it didn't help in my case.

Comment: @Sinatr "Are you blind" really!!!is that how you talk to people trying to help you?

Comment: If you wanna help or comment Duplicate, pay attention to the question first.

Comment: did even look at your question and the link I posted, no one know what SaveData() was maybe you could write better questions in the future.

Comment: `SuppressKeyPress` and `Handled` are set to True in my code as well. But didn't help, so I was looking for other solutions. Your link doesn't help in my case, so just do you business

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Please note that the answer provided by LarsTech ([below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230895/959631)) is a far better approach.

---

Sorry, I just realised that you have a MessageBox displaying.

What you can do is have a `Timer` and have it fire off the `SaveData()` method.

```
private void Timer1_Tick(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Timer1.Enabled = false;
    SaveData();
}
```

Then in your `TextBox` keypress event, do this:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    Timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

That seems to work...

Comment: Instead of using Timer, the more elegant solution is using this.BeginInvoke() to delay the MessageBox and prevent beeping. See LarsTech answer below.

Comment: @MarisB. Apologies, this answer was made a long time ago when I was just starting out. I agree that the answer below is a better approach. I can update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

From your comments, showing a MessageBox will interfere with your setting of the SuppressKeyPress property.

A work-around is to delay the showing of the MessageBox until after the method is completed:

```
void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => SaveData()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating your own textbox and handle the keydown event like so:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {          
            case (Keys.Return):
              /*
               * Your Code to handle the event
               * 
               */                   
                return;  //Not calling base method, to stop 'ding'
        }

        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```